# Why does assigning a string of a long value to filtercontext.httpcontext.response.statusdescription cause an error?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am assigning a string of length 833 to the

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = new String('a',833);
```

object and it is failing and giving me a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' exception.

I am overriding the OnException() method.

Why is this happening as I thought StatusDescription is just a normal string?

Comment: "clear, not showing any research effort, not useful" - as combination lead to somewhat negative score (as method's documentation explicitly mentions the exception and condition)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I read this as asking about the motivation for why the code works like that. I.e. a higher level why.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know the reason, but as you can see on [sourceof.net](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,6a946f5c51c77e42,references), there is a limit of 512 characters that can be assigned to `HttpResponse.StatusDescription`:

```
/*
 * Http status description string
 */

// Http status description string
//    Gets or sets the HTTP status string of output returned to the client.
public String StatusDescription {
    get {
        if (_statusDescription == null)
            _statusDescription = HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription(_statusCode);

        return _statusDescription;
    }

    set {
        if (_headersWritten)
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString(SR.Cannot_set_status_after_headers_sent));

        if (value != null && value.Length > 512)  // ASURT 124743
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        _statusDescription = value;
        _statusSet = true;
    }
}
```

It's also mentioned on MSDN: [HttpResponse.StatusDescription Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statusdescription(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Exceptions**
>
> - `HttpException` - `StatusDescription` is set after the HTTP headers have
>     been sent.
> - `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - The selected value has a
>     length greater than 512.

Answer (score 1):

While the http specification does not impose a limit, implementers will typically impose their own limit to prevent malicious attacks that increase server load by feeding parsers unbounded input.

E.g. [here's a Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/CF2rsUKNvwQ) where the developer of an http-based integration toolkit explains the limit in his code for this reason.